# Error during wrapup: unused argument (MARGIN = dots[[2]][[1]])

Tags: r

I have a table, but I just need four columns (x1,y1,x2,y2) to calculate something. But, I get this error "Error during wrapup: unused argument (MARGIN = dots[[2]][[1]])". I am not sure I am doing it right. I am a beginner at R.

```
x1 <- data.frame(LV_data_cleaned$x1)
y1 <- data.frame(LV_data_cleaned$y1)
x2 <- data.frame(LV_data_cleaned$x2)
y2 <- data.frame(LV_data_cleaned$y2)
x3 <- data.frame(LV_data_cleaned$x3)
y3 <- data.frame(LV_data_cleaned$y3)
Pab <- function(x1,y1,x2,y2){
  return(log(sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2)/sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1+y2)^2)))
}
mapply(LV_data_cleaned,
      FUN= Pab,
     MARGIN=2)
```

Comment: `mapply` doesn't have `MARGIN` argument.  Usage from `?mapply` is `mapply(FUN, ..., MoreArgs = NULL, SIMPLIFY = TRUE,
       USE.NAMES = TRUE)`.  Perhaps you may need `do.call(Pab, LV_data_cleaned)`

Comment: Try running `do.call(Pab, LV_data_cleaned[c("x1", "y1", "x2", "y2")])`

Comment: FYI: (1) Why do you assign to `x1`, `y1`, ..., and `y3` and not use them? (2) `data.frame(LV_data_cleaned$x1)` is going to result in a single-column frame with the column name of `LV_data_cleaned.x1`, perhaps not what you intend? (3) Related to my #1, if your definition of `x1` is intended to be used in your `Pab` function, then realize that `x1` is a *frame*, not a vector. While most of this math will likely still work without warning/error, it is fairly non-standard and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the function created, we can directly run it with `do.call`

```
do.call(Pab, LV_data_cleaned)
[1] -0.04541942  0.36487930  0.17183364  2.20397708 -0.15840202 
[6] -0.81112314 -0.14807592 -0.42281736 -0.22409245  0.44747989
```

If there are many columns in `LV_data_cleaned`, just subset the columns

```
do.call(Pab, LV_data_cleaned[c("x1", "y1", "x2", "y2")])
```

We don't need `Map` or `mapply` assuming `LV_data_cleaned` is a data.frame.  In addition, there is no `MARGIN` argument in `mapply`.  The usage of `mapply/Map` would be similar to the above in this case (but it is not needed)

```
do.call(mapply, c(FUN = Pab, LV_data_cleaned))
[1] -0.04541942  0.36487930  0.17183364  2.20397708 -0.15840202 
[6] -0.81112314 -0.14807592 -0.42281736 -0.22409245  0.44747989
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
LV_data_cleaned <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10 * 4), 10, 4, 
     dimnames = list(NULL, c("x1", "y1", "x2", "y2"))))
```